# Buy() function not acting as expected

Tags: solidity, mist, ethereum-wallet-dapp, myetherwallet

I am experimenting with the `MyAdvancedToken` code at:  https://www.ethereum.org/token

```
    function setPrices(uint256 newSellPrice, uint256 newBuyPrice) onlyOwner public {
        sellPrice = newSellPrice;
        buyPrice = newBuyPrice;
    }

    function buy() payable public {
        uint amount = msg.value / buyPrice;               // calculates the amount
        _transfer(this, msg.sender, amount);              // makes the transfers
    }
```

If the `amount purchased = msg.value/buyPrice`, how is it ever possible to buy a token that is worth less than 1ETH?  `buyPrice` cannot be a decimal less than 1. In other words, I want it so a person can send 1 ETH and receive 10 tokens.  This math does not allow that (`buyPrice` cannot be 0.1).

Some of the documentation says that `value` and `buyPrice` should be in wei, not ETH.  In that case, I could make the math work.  However, in testing using MyEtherWallet and the Ethereum Wallet application, I am seeing `msg.value` come over as ETH.  If I send 1 ETH, with `buyPrice = 10`, the user ends up buying 0.1 tokens.

Is there a trick to getting the `msg.value` to be wei instead of ETH?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within a contract, `msg.value` is always in Wei. Front-end applications will sometimes display values in Eth as a "convenience" to the user, but within the transaction it's always Wei.

Note that a similar thing is true for token values within contracts. For example, this `MyAdvancedToken` token has `decimals` set to 18 (the same as Ether). When you buy 0.1 tokens, internally you are actually buying 10<sup>17</sup> tokens. A user interface may use the `decimals` parameter to translate this to 0.1 for display.

---

[To expand on this now I'm no longer on mobile.]

For both Ether and tokens you've got two things going on:

1. The internal representation, which is always an integer. For Ether, this is Wei.
2. The user interface representation, which can be different.  UIs know that 1 Eth = 10^18 Wei (i.e. 18 decimal places). ERC20 tokens tell the UI how many internal units make up a whole token via the `decimals` parameter. This is often also 18, but does not need to be.

In your example, `MyAdvancedToken` has `decimals` equal to 18, the same as Ether. So you cannot issue more tokens than the amount of Ether coming in, since `buyPrice` is an integer of one or greater.

If you want to issue 10 tokens for 1 Eth, you can do one of the following:

- Set `buyPrice` to 1 and `decimals` to 17.  Each Wei will buy 1 token, but the UI will display it as 10x bigger.
- Set `buyPrice` to 10<sup>17</sup> and `decimals` to 0. Each Ether will buy 10 base tokens, and they will be displayed as whole tokens.
- Set `buyPrice` to 10<sup>x</sup> and `decimals` to `17 - x`.

Or you can forget about all of this and just multiply by the inverse of `buyPrice` (10) rather than dividing by buy price. This is probably the simplest.

---

This is all a huge headache of course. I really hate the ERC20 token `decimals` concept. Here's a [long discussion](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/724) about it. I favour hardcoding `decimals` to 0, fwiw.

Comment: In other words, in all the contracts made using that ethereum.org boilerplate code, a purchased token cannot have a value less than 1 ETH?  Thanks for the great answer.